# -1 reputation in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I just got -1 reputation in Stack Overflow but in the activity summary I can't see why that happened.

I downvoted an answer that has been deleted, that's all it comes to my mind that can be related to that issue, but still there is no information in the activity...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deleted posts does not appear in the activity list. if you want that 1 rep back, recalc your rep at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: I did that, and at the very end it says: ** total rep 423 :). Thanks.  What's the reason you get -1 for downvoting a post that later is deleted?

Comment: @Nobita, downvotes on answers are always -1 for downvoter. deletion of post is another case.